# Increment based on values in another cell

Tags: excel

Sorry this might be a very basic excel question. I need a formula to automatically fill the contents of column A based on the values in column B. Is this possible to do.

```
Column A     Column B
SG001        Singapore
MY001        Malaysia
SG002        Singapore
TH001        Thailand
```

Comment: `=LEFT(B2)&TEXT(COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2), "000")` is a start. To get the second character you would need a cross-reference table of countries and their [ISO 3166-1 two letter designation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Officially_assigned_code_elements) which you have failed to offer.

Answer (score 0):

First create a country code table, in say columns **F** and **G.**  Then in cell **A2** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$1:$G$6,2)&TEXT(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2)+1,"000")
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image: picture]